# Laravel scheduler cron options from database

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am new to laravel.

I am finding how can i execute schedules.
The schedule parameters (frequency, command) are stored in a mysql table.

I have thought a solution which is:
Use file_put_contents to write in app/Console/Kernel.

Any better idea would be welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Chris Pappas

Answer (score 7):

The frequency of a certain command is defined on multiple levels. The [Cron entry](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#introduction) on your server calls the schedular every minute. In your scheduler there are [frequency options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options) as well.

One of the possibilities to let paramaters that are stored in the database define the frequency of command executions is to add a executed_at field to the table and a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes) to your Commands model that validates the schedule parameters in your mysql table:

```
public function scopeReadyToExecute($query)
{
    return $query->where('executed_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString());
}
```

In this example the frequency is 5 minutes, of course you have to change this value according the the value in the frequency field.

Now, you could for example define master:command in Kernel.php to be executed every minute:

```
$schedule->command('master:command')->everyMinute()
```

In the handle of master:command you call the scope function to get the commands that are ready to execute:

```
public function handle()
{
    $commands = Command::readyToExecute()->get();

    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        $this->call($command->name)
    }
}
```

Each command that is ready to execute according to the parameters defined in your table will be executed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here in my solution.

app/Console/Kernel.php

```
    $report_schedules = ReportSchedule::all();
    foreach ($report_schedules as $report_schedule) {

        $method_name = (string)$report_schedule->report->method_name;
        $schedule->call(function () use ($method_name, $report_schedule) {
            $emailSchedules = new EmailSchedules();
            $email_List=array_unique(array_merge($report_schedule->users()->get()->lists("email")->toArray(), $report_schedule->groups()->with(["users"=>function ($query){$query->select("email");}])->get()->toArray()));
            $users=\App\User::whereIn("email",$email_List)->get(["first_name","last_name","email"]);
            $users_to=[];
            $emails_to=[];
            foreach($users as $user){
                array_push($users_to,$user->first_name." ".$user->last_name);
                array_push($emails_to,$user->email);
            }

            $emailSchedules->$method_name($emails_to,$users_to);
        })->cron($report_schedule->frequency)->name('mail')->timezone("Europe/Athens");
    }
```

Hope that help someone in the future.

Comment: adding or changing schedules in db requires restarting your daemon

Comment: @amd so you mean a live site connection loss about 10 seconds?